# Can I point my custom name server to the same domain IP?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, plesk

I have a domain name `example.com` point to 192.0.2.1

and I have :

```
ns1.example.com (custom ns) points also to 192.0.2.1
ns1.example.com (custom ns) points also to 192.0.2.1
```

Then I set the dns for "example.com" to be `ns1` & `ns2`

Is there any problem with this logic? Because I tried testing my domain with https://mxtoolbox.com and it gave me this result:

```
"Loop detected! We were referred back to 192.0.2.1"
```

Comment: I think the question is too vague. Would it be possible to provide the actual name servers and IP addresses?

Comment: I editted your post to put proper IP addresses from RFC5737. But I agree with @Halfgaar stop doing useless obfuscatio and provide the true name and IP addresses involved otherwise your question is useless. And due to the way you present it it looks like you have some misconceptions about DNS (to start with: having two NS records with the same IP is useless, if that is what you have done), so you may be better letting a third party handle it for you.